# I have error message " for file changes with StatReloader Exception in thread django-main-thread:"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have errors in configuration, and when I had been downloading the project from Github that error shown to me. Also, I tried to create a new project, so the project run.

How can I avoid this problem and solve it?

---

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediumeditor'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xampp/htdocs/athar/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/xampp/htdocs/athar/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1159, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Users\promi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 197, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError <<-  It's mostly like your environment problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `pip freeze` do you see `mediumeditor` listed?  If so, in your Django project `settings.py` file in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section, is `mediumeditor` listed there?

Those are the two places I would look to first.

Typical a module not found error is because it wasn't installed through pip or it wasn't listed as an app in the `INSTALLED_APPS` section in the `settings.py` file

As @Zhubei-Federer mentioned, it could be an environment issue, meaning your Django project might be pointing to a corrupt environment, or the python version or environment variables could be wrong.  There could be many errors that an environment issue can cause.

Comment: I did that and it's work well now, thanks for your help